# Deleting minimum from an array using unset in php

Tags: php

`unset(min($arr))` is not working in php

`min($arr)` do gives the minimum and unset($arr[1]) also works

any idea?

Comment: min($arr) returns the minimum value, not a reference, so you cannot use it as the unset parameter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
unset($arr[array_search(min($arr), $arr)]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use

```
array_sort($arr);
array_shift($arr);
```

That sorts it so the lowest is first and then pops it off the top.

Alternatively, you could `unset($arr[array_search(min($arr), $arr)]);`, but that seems rather inefficient.

Comment: i don't like this logic as it sorts the array so it will change position of other items as well which is not desired if user is going to use the array for further use

Comment: @SaketPatel since he hasn't specified that the keys are important then this is a perfectly valid solution.  I posted an alternative solution which would preserve the keys but is more inefficient.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [`array_reduce`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-reduce.php) over the list of array *keys*. That way you would have the index of the smallest entry so that you could unset it directly.

```
$data = array(8, 5, 7, 1, 4, 2);
print_r($data);

function mindex($min, $curr) {
  global $data;
  if (is_null($min) || $data[$curr] < $data[$min])
    return $curr;
  else
    return $min;
}

$min_index = array_reduce(array_keys($data), mindex);
unset($data[$min_index]);
print_r($data);
```

**OUTPUT**

```
Array
(
    [0] => 8
    [1] => 5
    [2] => 7
    [3] => 1
    [4] => 4
    [5] => 2
)
Array
(
    [0] => 8
    [1] => 5
    [2] => 7
    [4] => 4
    [5] => 2
)
```